# Repeating same input not showing

Tags: reactjs, laravel

I'm making an application using Laravel and React.
I made an event in laravel to display data in real time and I'm using **"[React Transition Group](http://reactcommunity.org/react-transition-group/transition-group)"** to add an animation to the added data.

The problem is, when I'm adding data normally without this package, the data is showing correctly, but once added, the animation and data are working fine except when repeating the same data.

For example if I add in `{patient.nom}` and `{patient.prenom}` values such as `John` & `Doe`. They will appear, but if **I put them again, they will not, but in database they are registered perfectly.**

After some tests I'm pretty sure it has to do with the `key` in

```
<CSSTransition 
          key={patient.nom,patient.prenom}
            timeout={500}
            classNames="item"><CSSTransition>
```

Whole component :

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import Echo from "laravel-echo";
import {
  ListGroup,
  Button,
} from 'react-bootstrap';
import {
  CSSTransition,
  TransitionGroup,
} from 'react-transition-group';

import './styles.css';
 
class Patient extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            patients : [],
        };
    }

        componentDidMount() {
            axios.get('api/patients')
            .then(response => {this.setState({patients: response.data})})
            .catch(err => console.log(err));
            
            window.Echo.channel('home')
                .listen('NewPatient', newPatientData => {
                    this.setState({
                        patients: this.state.patients.concat(newPatientData)
                    })
                }, e => {
                    console.log("Error", e)
                })
        }

        render() {
          return (
            <div>
              <TransitionGroup>


{this.state.patients.slice(0).reverse().map(patient => 

              <CSSTransition 
              key={patient.nom,patient.prenom}
                timeout={500}
                classNames="item">
                  <ListGroup.Item>                 
                {patient.nom} {patient.prenom}
                </ListGroup.Item>  
              </CSSTransition>
  )} 

              </TransitionGroup>
            </div>
          )
        }
      }

export default Patient;
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved. As I read in an article:

> Generate a unique id for every item and use it as key when
> rendering the list.

So I didn't have an unique id in my list, because the event that was broadcasting did not send id.

So in the final result in the key I should have  `key={patient.id}`  , like that every element in the list would have a unique id from database.